# How to write String template file with multiple loop elements?

Tags: python, string, templates, file-handling, stringtemplate

I have small issue in writing for loop elements in string template as follows:  when I try to make a string templete from three loop elements I can able to print only the last element not the first two elements. I beleive that the error is because of some issues in writing file but I couldnt get what is the actual problem is with my code. So If some one could you kindly help me with this.

```
My SCRIPT:

from string import Template
import os

AMONIOACIDS = {'A': 'ALA', 'C': 'CYS', 'E': 'GLU', 'D': 'ASP', 'G': 'GLY',
           'F': 'PHE', 'I': 'ILE', 'H': 'HIS', 'K': 'LYS', 'M': 'MET',
           'L': 'LEU', 'N': 'ASN', 'Q': 'GLN', 'P': 'PRO', 'S': 'SER',
           'R': 'ARG', 'T': 'THR', 'W': 'TRP', 'V': 'VAL', 'Y': 'TYR'}

rPrS={'C': '102', 'A': '104','H': '12'}


a=[]
b=[]
count=1
for single, third in AMONIOACIDS.iteritems():
   for rS,rP in rPrS.iteritems():
       if rS == single:
            a.append(["s"+str(count)+"=selection(mdl1.chains["+chain+"].residues["+rP+"])"])
            b.append(["s"+str(count)+".mutate(residue_type='"+third+"')"])


str='''Loop elements\n'''
for i,j in zip (a,b):
    i=''.join(i)
    j=''.join(j)
    str+='''$i\n'''
    str+='''$j\n'''
str=Template(str)
str.substitute(i=i, j=j)
file = open(os.getcwd() + '/' + 'model.py', 'w')
file.write(str.substitute(i=i,j=j))
file.close()
```

Expected ouput:

```
Loop elements
s1=selection(mdl1.chains[A].residues[104])
s1.mutate(residue_type='ALA')
s2=selection(mdl1.chains[A].residues[102])
s2.mutate(residue_type='CYS')
s3=selection(mdl1.chains[A].residues[12])
s3.mutate(residue_type='HIS')
```

What I am getting :

```
Loop elements
s3=selection(mdl1.chains[A].residues[12])
s3.mutate(residue_type='HIS')
s3=selection(mdl1.chains[A].residues[12])
s3.mutate(residue_type='HIS')
s3=selection(mdl1.chains[A].residues[12])
s3.mutate(residue_type='HIS')
```

Comment: Just `print` the `str` before converting it to a `Template` and you will see your error.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I am getting printed lines like as follows:Loop elements
$i
$j
$i
$j
$i
$j . here Its printing consequently but I couldnt get from where error start

Comment: Can I ask why you are writing code that writes this code at all?

Comment: Sorry I didnt follow your question but The code I am writing  for making templates of (model.py) script with multiple residue positions and residues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is getting its substitution values from the last values of `i` and `j` from the `for` loop. You need to persist values from the previous iteration. How? You could use a dictionary and a count to store and distinguish values at each iteration.

You can [substitute values in a template using a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template). I have used the count variable to create corresponding dictionary keys at each iteration: `i_0`, `i_1`, `i_2`, and  `j_0`, `j_1`, `j_2`. These same names are used as identifiers in the template `$i_0`, `$i_1`, `$i_2`, and  `$j_0`, `$j_1`, `$j_2`.

`safe_substitute` safely substitutes the value at each key into the template e.g key `i_0` to the template identifier `$i_0`.

---

The dictionary stores all values of `i` and `j` at each iteration, and the substitution in your template is done taking the appropriate values at each key in the dictionary. This part should fix it:

```
# your previous lines of code

count = 0
d = {}
s='''Loop elements\n'''
for i,j in zip (a,b):
    d['i_{}'.format(count)] = ''.join(i)
    d['j_{}'.format(count)] = ''.join(j)
    s+='$i_{}\n'.format(count)
    s+='$j_{}\n'.format(count)
    count += 1

print(str)
print(d)
s=Template(s)
file = open(os.getcwd() + '/' + 'model.py', 'w')
file.write(s.safe_substitute(d))
file.close()
```

I have replaced the name `str` with `s` to avoid shadowing the builtin `str`. No other changes are required in the preceding code blocks before the fix.

Comment: Thank you somuch . If you dont mine can you add details of your code would be really helpful.

Comment: @DarwinCode I have added more details :)

Comment: Thankyou somuch Its really helped alot

Comment: Hi Moses , Here is some issue that when I do safe_substitute(d) with some other variable its like follows file.write(MM.safe_substitute(Model=Model,pdb=pdb,chains=chains,MDLWRR=MDLWRR,OPTSS=OPTSS,OPMW=OPMW,d=d)). Its printing only  follow the lines $i_0
$j_0
$i_1
$j_1
$i_2
$j_2 May I know why?

Comment: Use `substitute` in this case for direct substitutions. `safe_substitute` comes handy when substituting from dictionaries.

Comment: if I give like as follows file.write(MM.substitute(d=d,Model=Model,pdb=pdb,chains=chains,MDLWRR=MDLWRR,OPTSS=OPTSS,OPMW=OPMW)) I am getting error as follows:    file.write(MM.substitute(d=d,Model=Model,pdb=pdb,chains=chains,MDLWRR=MDLWRR,OPTSS=OPTSS,OPMW=OPMW))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 172, in substitute
    return self.pattern.sub(convert, self.template)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/string.py", line 162, in convert
    val = mapping[named]
KeyError: 'i_0'

Comment: Try: `file.write(MM.safe_substitute(d, Model=Model,pdb=pdb,chains=chains,MDLWRR=MDLWRR,OP‌​TSS=OPTSS,OPMW=OPMW,d=d))`, but are `Model`, `pdb` ... identifiers in your template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116380/discussion-between-darwincode-and-moses-koledoye).